# Legal Java operations with integers and char

Tags: java, char, int

So the following:

```
char x = 88;

int number = 8 + 'E';

char x = 'a' + 8;
```

are legal Java operations right?

'Cause my Java teacher's saying that **ONLY** characters enclosed in single quotes are legal for `char` and I have a test tomorrow so I want to make sure that I'm right and that she doesn't mark me wrong.

Also, I tried playing around with `int` and things like `int x = 40 + 'a'` and `char x = 5 + 'd'` and they all yield the predicted results (If I refer to the ASCII chart) without any sort of errors.

Comment: There's a vast difference between "legal" and "a good idea" :-)

Comment: If you get marked wrong for something that's actually correct, challenge your teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use/assign both an integer (ASCII) value or a character itself to a `char` variable. The same value gets assigned to the variable ultimately.

But your teacher may just be trying to suggest you a **best practice**, wherein using the characters rather than ASCII values is much more readable.

Comment: This part of your answer is incorrect - *"Both get assigned to the variable as a byte ultimately"* - in Java, `char` values are unsigned 16 bit quantities.

Comment: Java `char`s are 16-bit unsigned values intended to represent UTF-16 code units. They are not necessarily bytes.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: And they're not necessarily characters. ☺

Comment: @Mechanical snail - and that is why he carefully used the term "UTF-16 code unit" rather than "Unicode code point".

Comment: No she said that `char x = '5'` is valid and `char x = 5` won't work but I convinced her today

Answer (score 1):

`char` to `int` conversion is called  `widening conversions`. In widening conversions, values do not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value where as `int` to `char` conversion is called `narrowing conversions`.  With narrowing conversion you may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision.

For more information on primitive conversions [refer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html) this document.

Comment: Yeah I found that out through one of our exercises

Answer (score 0):

If that is actually what your teacher said, she is incorrect, and you should be able to write a program that proves this.

However, it is not a good idea to use integer literals as character values because it obscures the meaning of your program.  (Perhaps that is what she was saying, and you misunderstood her.)

Comment: Yes I wrote a program that proved that and yes I know it's a bad idea 'cause I don't know what `'e' + 'a'` equals to. And no I didn't misunderstand her. I talked to her today and she said that you can only do `char x = '5'` and not `char x = 5` but I convinced her otherwise

Answer (score 0):

"char", "int", "byte", "short", or "long" are all just names for things that hold a bunch of bits strung together. Together, they're known as the [integral types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#85587).

Likewise, all of these are literal values that Java knows how to represent as a bunch of bits: 0, '0', 1, '0', -1, 2147483647, 'a', 'A', '~', ... You get the picture. And I'm pretty sure from your question that you already know that 0 and '0' aren't the same thing.

Any of the values I listed, plus others like them, can be assigned to any of the integral types, though sometimes you have to force them to fit (like `byte b = (byte) i`, where `i` is an `int`), and you might lose some of the bits that make up the values when you force them.

So yes, all the operations you listed are valid because you're just combining different integer literals in different ways and assigning them to an integral type.

P.S. If you're new to Java, don't try to read too much from that "integral types" link at once, or your head might asplode.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, what is legal and what is a good idea is not always the same.

```
char ch = '0';
ch *= 1.1;
// ch == '4'
```

Watch for infinite loops

```
for(char ch = Character.MIN_VALUE; ch <= Character.MAX_VALUE; ch++) // infinite loop
```

Another thing you can do with chars which is questionable is to convert straight from byte[] to a String.

```
byte[] bytes = 
String text = new String(bytes, 0);
```

This works for ASCII-7 text but shouldn't be used in general.